# How to create a histogram of a nn model's prediction

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, histogram

My NN model predicts the labels and the scores of images (see sample image, the scores are the floats below the image and the labels are the attributes on the right)

[image: example output]

I want to make a histogram to show which attributes (labels) are predicted more. So I was thinking to index the labels and find their count but I don't know how to do it.

I append all the outputs in an array `(preds_array)` and the `attributes` is the labels array and then I did this:

```
outputs_array = [j for i in zip(preds_array, attributes) for j in i] #zip the output scores with their labels



#The outputs_array looks like this#
    [0.21103, array(['dirty'], dtype=object), 0.99764, array(['daylight'], dtype=object), 0.000802, array(['night'], dtype=object)

%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(42)

plt.hist(outputs_array, density=False, bins=30)
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Predicted Labels');
```

But it returns an error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting the counts of how many predictions were made for each label?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

attributes = ['a','b','c','a']

predictions_dict ={}

for attr in attributes:
   if attr in predictions_dict.keys():
       predictions_dict[attr] += 1
   else:
       predictions_dict[attr] = 1


plt.bar(predictions_dict.keys(), predictions_dict.values())
plt.show()
```

If you are wanting histograms of the scores for each label I would recommend something similar, however, based on what you have above, it looks like you will only have the scores for each class when it was the predicted class. But, if that is what you want, here is how you could turn what you have above into histograms of those scores for each label

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#making up arrays of labels and scores because I don't know all of yours
labels = ['a','b','c']
attributes = np.random.choice(labels, 100)
scores = np.random.random(100)

d = {key:[] for key in labels}

for attribute, score in zip(attributes, scores):
    d[attribute].append(score)

for attribute in d.keys():
    plt.hist(d[attribute], alpha=0.3, label=attribute)

plt.xlabel('score')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you know all of the labels ahead of time, you could have the dictionary preset with all of the keys as the labels and the values as 0 so your plot would include labels that were never predicted. It would also simplify the loop as you wouldn't need an if else statement.  You may also have to use .item() or .cpu() if attributes is a pytorch tensor to get just the label out

Comment: I do know them. I have one array for the labels (attributes array) and one for the scores which are the predictions for each label. I thought I had to combine them first since they are separate. And have one array with the predicted scores and their labels. What I showed in the example is after the training when I have iterate the whole dataset.

Comment: I have edited the above to do the same thing, but for the scores. I think what I call scores would be preds_array in your question.